# ActionBarSherlock custom NavigationDrawer icon

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm implementing NavigationDrawer with ActionBarSherlock and now I'm trying to implement custom icon for opening and closing the drawer. I already set my own icon (white) but I'm not able to get rid of that grey default icon.

in onCreateOptionsMenu I'm doing this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // does not display activity title
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_background)); // blue background 
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.side_menu_button); // white icon
```

[image]

The picture shows difference when navigation drawer is closed (first) and open (second picture).

Is there any way to do it programmatically? Or is there even some way to do it? I hope it is.

Thank you.

EDIT: This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are currently doing is setting the icon on the ActionBar, which is different from setting the icon of the ActionBarDrawerToggle, which is what you want to be dealing with. If you look at the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) and find the constructor, you'll see there's a place to specify a custom Drawable to be used by the toggle.

Comment: thank you, you are right, but this is not what I intented. I don't want to replace that grey icon with white, because it will slide like the gray did. Please take a look at edit in my post and you will see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can create a small, transparent drawable resource and pass it to the ActionBarDrawerToggle, that's the simplest way to do it without rewriting a lot of the classes yourself.

Comment: I actually did, instead of setting getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.side_menu_button); i used it in ActionBarDrawerToggle constructor as you suggested, but this drawable will then slide in onclick event to one side, as can be seen in the first and second picture. I don't want this behaviour.

Comment: Don't use your drawable, use a small, empty, transparent one like I said. It can be as simple as a 1x1 transparent PNG. That way you still technically have a drawable, but you won't see anything and you get the behavior you want.

Comment: HA! Got it.. I'm not sure if this is right solution, but I can't deny it's workig.